# How to exit from outer loop if inner loop is getting failed using Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I terminate the whole main program if inner loop has any issue using batch command? Below is my code.

Here I need to exit from main outer loop if value found in inner loop is X, but currently my code is getting exit from inner loop only.

```
For %%A in (alpha beta gamma) DO (
   Echo Outer loop %%A
   Call :inner 
)
Goto :eof

:inner
For %%B in (U V W X Y Z) DO (
   if %%B==X ( exit /b 2 )
   Echo    Inner loop    Outer=%%A Inner=%%B
   
)
exit /b 1
```

**Output** : it should be like below only.

```
Outer loop alpha
   Inner loop    Outer=alpha Inner=U
   Inner loop    Outer=alpha Inner=V
   Inner loop    Outer=alpha Inner=W
```

Comment: Just insert `if ErrorLevel 2 goto :EOF` after the `call` command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set an exit code (errorlevel). Just react on it:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%A in (alpha beta gamma) DO (
   Echo Outer loop %%A
   Call :inner 
   if !errorlevel! equ 2 (echo inner loop failed & exit /b 2)
)
Goto :eof

:inner
For %%B in (U V W X Y Z) DO (
   if %%B==X ( exit /b 2 )
   Echo    Inner loop    Outer=%%A Inner=%%B

)
exit /b 1
```

Aschipfl suggested "*Just insert `if ErrorLevel 2 goto :EOF` after the `call` command line*"
That might be a good idea (and avoids delayed expansion), but be aware that `if errorlevel 2` actually means "if errorlevel is 2 or higher". If your inner loop only ever returns `0` or `2`, that's definitively the better solution. When it may return more possible errorlevels, you have to use extreme care handling them with `if errorlevel`. (That's the reason, I chose `if !errorlevel!` instead)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Just 1 doubt, suppose that  if i have multiple inner function so do i need to maintain errorlevel for each inner loop?

for e.g. 
   Call :inner1
   call :inner2
   call :inner3
   
   how to restrict the execution using a single error level if any one got failed?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to break the outer loop as soon as one of the inner loops fails or do you want to execute all inner loops regardless of their success and just know afterward if one of them failed?

Comment: I have to break the outer loop if there are multiple inner loop and any one of inner loop fails.

Comment: just repeat the two lines `call ...` and `if ...` for each inner loop. (when needed, you can change the `exit` to a `goto :error`; And of course a label `:error` somewhere to do something in case of any "inner-loop-error")

Comment: (Btw: Any `goto` will break all loops. So `if %%B==X goto :ExitLoops` within the inner loop will cancel all currently running loops and jump to the label `ExitLoops` (instead of returning to the outer loop)

Comment: i have already tried using if %%B==X goto :ExitLoops , but it is getting return to outer loop.